# It is halal to rename as a born Muslim

Tags: halal-haram, hadith, practical-islam

### I know it is different or maybe rare for Muslims ##                                          --

*Even born as a Muslim I did not have enough knowledge of Islam after 13 years of my life I realized my life was not in the order of Allah, it was a message from him by give Umrah change to go Mecca still as I said I do not have enough knowledge about Islam I did not perform very well but still it was useful and encourage me toward the steps now I am 14 years old and I am on a journey of improvement and change life both ways professionally and personally, So during this journey, I have a question can I rename my Muslim name which gives me more feel of it*